# C++ inger to array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, c++14, c++98

i have made a function in the C++ 14 compiler, and i want to make it run on the C++ 98.
The function takes an integer number and sums it's digits, by converting the integer to an array of string.

The code the for the code for the 14 version is:

```
#include <iostream>

int digitSum(int num){
    int sum = 0;
    auto stringOfVal = to_string(num);
    int numbers[stringOfVal.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringOfVal.size() ;i++){
        numbers[i] = stringOfVal[i] - '0';
        sum=sum + numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The code for the 98 version is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int digitSum(int num){
    int sum = 0;
    stringstream temp_str;
    temp_str << num;
    char const* stringOfVal = temp_str.str().c_str();
    int numbers[sizeof(stringOfVal)];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(stringOfVal) ;i++){
        numbers[i] = stringOfVal[i] -'0';
        sum=sum + numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It compile's with no problems but the second function for the 98 compiler doesn't return the what i want.

I tried to convert the integer to an array of string, from a method i found but, it doesn't return the correct value.

Comment: `char const* stringOfVal = temp_str.str().c_str();` creates a dangling pointer as `stringstream::str()` returns a temporary string.  Any dereference of `stringOfVal` is then Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `int numbers[sizeof(stringOfVal)]` is going the be the size of a pointer not the length of the c-string pointed to by `stringOfVal`.  If you change the code to get the length at runime you should note that: Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) are a non-standard compiler extension and I recommend you use `std::vector`

Comment: try `std::string stringOfVal = temp_str.str();`, and get rid of the `numbers` array as you don't need it (just the sum)

Comment: There's no need for that intermediate string. Just extract digits one at a time: `while (num != 0) { sum += num % 10; num /= 10; }`.

Comment: Note that `stringstream` has an `>>` operator that extracts a `char`, so you can use a much simpler loop: `char digit; while (temp_str >> digit) sum += (digit - '0');`.

Comment: Your C++14 version is also incorrect, since `int numbers[stringOfVal.size()]` is a VLA.  VLA's are not part of standard C++.  In both cases, however, you can redefine `numbers` as `std::vector<int> numbers`.   I'll leave working out the correct size of that vector (which needs to be set before the loop) as an exercise.